# How to block Twitter login pop up on a network level?

Tags: networking, router, browser, asuswrt

On windows there is browser plugins to block elements of a website in real time (right clicking on element for example) but how would I go about blocking this specific element on a network level for all devices including mobile browsers.

For example going to Twitter and it asks you to login, I can just select and block this element but I am unable to do it on mobile browsers so how would one go about blocking this element on a router level?

Comment: The browser would need the ability to block specific elements. Only a few mobile browsers support this at all, such as Firefox on Android. Given your requirements, I don't believe what you are asking is impossible. That said, is this a business environment? Are these company owned phones and computers? What is your MDM tool? And perhaps, what problem are you actually trying to solve? You THINK you want to block page elements, but stepping back what is the original problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: +1 for why?  If it is to continue browsing without having to login you can't.  Disable the login pop-up and likely you won't even be able to browse Twitter anonymously up to the point it would have popped up.  Why not redirect all Twitter urls to a url that supports anonymous browsing instead?